# Subtract date from Jinja expression

Tags: date, ansible, jinja2, subtraction

I want to remove 1 month from `current_date_operation` in Ansible task. This is what I tried:

```yaml
vars:
  # for example current
  current_date_operation: "{{ ansible_date_time.date }}" 
  previous_date_operation : "{{ '%Y-%m-%d'|strftime(current_date_operation.epoch|int - 2592000) }}"
```

Unfortunately, the above code is giving the following error:

> "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'epoch'

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Remove one month means? do you mean if the date is 14/01/2020, you need it as 14/12/2019? or subtract 30 days from the current date?

Comment: Welcome to SO @jumpman. `it's not working` is never an accurate description of your problem. Please edit your question, show the result or error of your current task and describe the expected behavior. Take some time to get accustomed to the site and the way it works by reading the help section of the site. A good entry point is [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes, I just want subtract 1 month from current_date_operation
Please, find the error below
"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'epoch'

Answer (score 2):

In your `vars` declaration, your are first getting the `date` key from object `ansible_date_time`.

On the next line, you are using that set variable (which is a string) and call on it the key `epoch` which does not exists as it is a property of the parent object (i.e. `ansible_date_time`). Since your var declaration cannot be parsed correctly, the var in itself is undefined.

The following playbook demonstrate you can get the expected result by fixing your vars definition:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
 
  vars:
    current_date_operation: "{{ ansible_date_time.date }}"
    previous_date_operation : "{{ '%Y-%m-%d' | strftime(ansible_date_time.epoch | int - 2592000) }}"
 
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: current_date_operation
    - debug:
        var: previous_date_operation
```

Test run:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml 

PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "current_date_operation": "2020-01-14"
}

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "previous_date_operation": "2019-12-15"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answers, but in case you want calculate the previous_date_operation from ansible. Do we need convert string to date before ? If yes how to do ?

Comment: I calculated the date in the above POC from your requirments in ansible without any whatsoever conversion.